# SVG File Not Render Simulatenously on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, svg, splash-screen

I've tried react-native-svg for load my svg image for SplashScreen Page in My Project. But Logo Image Appears slower after the text. The Text itself and the logo are the same one svg file

[The Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Gba.png)

[Then the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EEUG.png)

Here's My Code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {Logo} from '../../assets';

export default class Splash extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.navigation.replace('MainApp');
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.pages}>
        <Logo />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pages: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

Here's My [Svg File](https://gist.github.com/ahmadfatihin/e98f65c43b21cdde5a14db8e178bdac6)

Answer (score 0):

the SVG markup as provided is incomplete. Adding the required closing tags

```
</defs> and </svg>
```

to the end allowed me to view it, but doing so made it evident that it does not actually contain an image, only a reference to one. It does make space for the image using a rect element at the top of the document, but its just a placeholder.

```
<rect width="271.688" height="271.688" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
```

The only part of your logo that is actually encoded into the svg as a vector is the text (as a path element). The svg is using a 'use' tag to reference an image with id "image0", but there is no node with that id anywhere in the markup you shared, so it is hard to troubleshoot further.

```
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.000333333)"/>
```

Are you sure you pasted the entire contents of the svg? It appears to be fetching remote content and if that's the case, you may just be at the mercy of whatever server hosts the image

Comment: Im using figma for export my Icon to SVG. I just updated my svg file to entire contents of the svg.